# Flutter how to align text in bottom of column

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to align a text in bottom of a column but it doesn't work.

I am using this code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).doc(widget.payload).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              return Container(color: Colors.amberAccent,child: const Column(children: [
                Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,child: Text('Bottom text'),)]));
                    },)   
          )
                
            
          
    );
  }
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what I can do to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To push the text to the bottom, set the `Column`'s `MainAxisAlignment` to `end`:

```dart
 Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, // <-- Set this
            children: [
              Text('Hello World!'),
            ],
          )
```

By default, it's at `start`.

Or: use a `Spacer`:

> `Spacer` creates an adjustable, empty spacer that can be used to tune the spacing between widgets in a `Flex` container, like `Row` or `Column`.

```dart
Column(
            children: [
              Spacer(),
              Text('Hello World!'),
            ],
          )
```

Result (in both cases)

[image]